# Edit a default knitr pdf

Tags: pdf, knitr

After multiple test and try I got a pdf from my script using knitr. Almost everything its right but I have some problems with default output: Date and sessionInfo. Also kableExtra library got me error.

I am not using R-studio...

Example of my script:

```
library(xtable)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

#My first pdf with knitr
data(mtcars)

tabla=mtcars%>%
count(am) 

kable(tabla, caption="tabla uno")
```

My commands to compile my script and get a pdf:

```
library(knitr)
setwd("C:/Users/Desktop")
knitr::stitch("C:/Users/Desktop/script.R")
```

In my pdf result below, you can see that pdf document begin with the date and finish with sessionInfo. I would like edit the date and put my own header and text and would like delete sessionInfo too.  Also you can see that kable table is at the end of document and not in the correct order. Also I did try to add echo=FALSE, to avoid show command to make table but without success...:

[image: pdf1]
[image: pdf2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you create your document with a YAML header to set variables like author, date, and title. Then you can combine regular text with code chunks as below.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Rodrigo"
date: "9/9/2019"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(xtable)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

```

# My first pdf with knitr

Some random text followed by a code block.
```{r}
# A comment
data(mtcars)

tabla=mtcars%>%
count(am) 
```

Here's the table. The code that printed the table has been supressed with `echo = FALSE`.

```{r echo = FALSE}
kable(tabla, caption="tabla uno") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position")
```

More text
````

The output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I try run using your script with knitr::stitch("C:/Users/Desktop/Gregory_script.R"), but gave me the same result before. What command are you using to compile?

Comment: I am not using R-studio, I am using 2 R scripts: one to compile and the other get my tables and graphs.

Comment: I'm compiling it with the RStudio IDE, which calls `rmarkdown::render()`. I haven't been able to track exactly how that's being called, i.e. what is the exact set of arguments being passed.

Comment: I realize that you use R-studio, I did try with rmarkdown::render() , but give error: Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).

Comment: I think the basic workflow is use knitr to go from Rmarkdown to markdown, pandoc to go from markdown to LaTeX, the pdfLaTeX to compile the pdf.

Comment: Yes, I did try with pandoc and others some days ago but I dont got success, I am able to get your pdf with R-studio. Anyway I will search and try others methods... Thank Gregory!